# jquery dataTable not working on ajax data

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I am working on dataTable 1.10.3. After generating table dataTable not working anymore. I have tried this

```
//my ajax success 

done(function (response) {
            var pcks = '';
            for (var i = 1; i < response.length; i++) {
                pcks += '<tr><td>' + response[i].load_number + '</td></tr>'
            }
            $('#packages_row').html(pcks);
            $('.unloadcTable4').dataTable().fnDestroy();
            $('.unloadcTable4').DataTable();
        });
```

My table showing nicely with dataTable sorting option but when I click to sort then show "No data available in table"

[image]

I do not want to use dataTable ajax stuff to generate my table. Now Is there any way to reinitialize dataTable on ajax table?

Comment: I'm not familiar with datatable, but maybe you can try to use the datatable api to clear the table, then in your loop use the datatable api to also add the rows.

Comment: yes helped. good idea